# How to you filter out a map without using for loop or forEach and get it in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

how do you filter out a map without using for loop or forEach and get it in an array?
so below I have a map `carMap` and an array `isPresentArr`  and when iterating `isPresentArr` I should get the `result`

```
const carMap = {
'1' : {id: '1', isPresent: true},
'2' : {id: '2', isPresent: true},
'3' : {id: '3', isPresent: true},
'4' : {id: '4', isPresent: true},
'5' : {id: '5', isPresent: true},
}
const isPresentArr = ['1','5']
const result = [{id: '1', isPresent: true},{id: '5', isPresent: true}]
```

```
const result = isPresentArr ?.filter((id) => { if (Object.keys(carMap).includes(id)) { return carMap[id] } })
```

I tried the above filter but am getting the result as `['1','5']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The `filter()` method creates a shallow copy of a portion of a given array, filtered down to just the elements from the given array that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Instead of filter use map:

```js
const carMap = {
'1' : {id: '1', isPresent: true},
'2' : {id: '2', isPresent: true},
'3' : {id: '3', isPresent: true},
'4' : {id: '4', isPresent: true},
'5' : {id: '5', isPresent: true},
}
const isPresentArr = ['1','5'];

const result = isPresentArr?.map((id) => { if (Object.keys(carMap).includes(id)) { return carMap[id] } })
console.log(result);//[{id: '1', isPresent: true},{id: '5', isPresent: true}]
```